# Regex return bad string

Tags: c#, regex

*in string* **"<-6838.36,-6723.11,0,0> <-7091.07,-6554.64,133,0> <-368,-368,0,1> <-400,-432,0,1> <-336,-432,0,1> <-304,-368,0,1> "**

*pattern1* `@"\<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),0\>";`

*pattern2* `@"\<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),1\>";`

*result* **1:"-6838.36" 2:"-6723.11" 3:"0,0> <-7091.07,-6554.64,133,0> <-368,-368,0"**

*need*: **1:"-6838.36" 2:"-6723.11" 3:"0"**

code:

```
string instring = "<-6838.36,-6723.11,0,0> <-7091.07,-6554.64,133,0> <-368,-368,0,1> <-400,-432,0,1> <-336,-432,0,1> <-304,-368,0,1> ";
string myteamheroes = @"\<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),0\>";
string enemyheroes = @"\<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),1\>";
MatchCollection collmytmheros = Regex.Matches(instring, myteamheroes);
MatchCollection collenemytmheros = Regex.Matches(instring, enemyheroes);

var us_EN = new CultureInfo("en-US");
foreach (Match herodata in collmytmheros)
{
    String sX = herodata.Groups[1].Value;
    String sY = herodata.Groups[2].Value;
    String sR = herodata.Groups[3].Value;

    double fX = float.Parse(sX, us_EN) + 7250.0d;
    double fY = float.Parse(sY, us_EN) + 7950.0d;
    int fR = int.Parse(sR);
    // here error
    //...other code

}

foreach (Match herodata in collenemytmheros)
{
    String sX = herodata.Groups[1].Value;
    String sY = herodata.Groups[2].Value;
    String sR = herodata.Groups[3].Value;

    // MessageBox.Show("1:\"" + sX +"\"2:\"" +  sY + "?" + "\"3:\"" +  "?");

    double fX = float.Parse(sX, us_EN) + 7250.0d;
    double fY = float.Parse(sY, us_EN) + 7950.0d;

    int fR = int.Parse(sR);
    // here error
    //... other code

}
```

Did I wrote anything wrong?

Comment: instring is **(string)Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\DH\\misc", "AfterStartDH", string.Empty);**

Comment: I can't replicate the issue with the code posted above. I'm getting the desired values. Maybe encoding problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're doing, so a regex might not be the best way to go about parsing your data. That said, I think the problem you're having is that the `(.*?),0\>` section will run past the end of your small groups of `<data>`, and run into the next set to obtain a match.

If you're sure there are only going to be numbers in there, you can alter your regex to be more specific:

e.g `<([\d-.]+),([\d-.]+),([\d-.]+),0>` (with a 1 instead of the 0 for your 'enemies').

Answer (score 2):

Could try the following regular expressions to match the results:

Pattern 1

```
\<([-0-9.]+),([-0-9.]+),([-0-9.]+),0\>
```

Patter 2

```
\<([-0-9.]+),([-0-9.]+),([-0-9.]+),1\>
```